# Is it possible to tell when /dev/kmsg has been ratelimited?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, systemd, dmesg

The Linux kernel developers decided by default to ratelimit messages to /dev/kmsg.  This was because they did not like the amount of messages written by systemd, particularly when `debug` is passed on the kernel command line.

systemd exceeds this limit even without enabling debug messages.

```
[    5.879211] systemd: 18 output lines suppressed due to ratelimiting
```

This is the only such message in my kernel log (`dmesg`) at the moment.  So I might think it means that only 18 successive lines were lost, ending around t=5.879211.  In some sense this would be a fairly limited loss.  I probably wouldn't need to worry about it unless I noticed some of the very early boot units (pre-journald) were failing.

So, is that right?  Is there a circumstance where this analysis could mislead me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this idea is pretty wrong.  Firstly, this message does not necessarily represent a single block of 18 successive systemd messages having been lost.  Secondly, you can't tell when /dev/kmsg has been ratelimited if the process still has it open for writing.  You only get a message about it once the process closes /dev/kmsg.  The message shows a count of all the suppressed lines from that writer.

---

Each individual writer (file descriptor) to `/dev/kmsg` gets it's own ratelimit struct.  [And as part of the initialization...](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14/source/kernel/printk/printk.c#L967)

```
ratelimit_set_flags(&user->rs, RATELIMIT_MSG_ON_RELEASE);
```

the ratelimit is set to only log on release.  That is, when the file descriptor is closed.  For a long-running process, this might be less than helpful... and the init system i.e. systemd definitely counts as a long-running process.

The reason you see this log message, is that systemd from the initrd closes /dev/kmsg before it `exec()`s systemd from the system's root filesystem.

So the messages lost during the initrd aren't necessarily lost as a block.  There could be several different blocks of lost messages, so the log would not be as straightforward to analyze as I had thought.

Also any number of messages could have been lost later on, from the time between `exec()`ing systemd from the root filesystem, up to the point systemd stops logging to the /dev/kmsg altogether and switches to `journald`.  And indeed they are, which we can see during shutdown (using a console that remains on, like a serial console).  When systemd `exec()`s systemd-shutdown, /dev/kmsg is automatically closed, and we see

```
[  OK  ] Reached target Final Step.
         Starting Reboot...
[   76.318839] systemd-shutdow: 32 output lines suppressed due to ratelimiting
...
```

This is all in contrast to certain ratelimited messages from the kernel e.g. `kauditd_printk_skb: 32 callbacks suppressed`.  In this case RATELIMIT_MSG_ON_RELEASE is not used.